# What is the English name for Burmese Black Tea?

Tags: tea, asian-cuisine, burmese-cuisine

I reside part time in Bangkok where there is vibrant Burmese community operating Burmese restaurants and shops especially in Phra Khanong (พระโขนง) area.

Often when I sit to rest in Burmese restaurants for a snack or for a meanl there are teapots with what I can name as "Black tea" which for me is very strong in its caffeinerig effect, like drinking 5 cups of green tea or 5 cups of weak coffee, perhaps.
This Black Tea beverage is served hot.

What is the English name of it? Is it made of [Camellia sinensis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camellia_sinensis) in general or a particular cultivar or a totally different plant?

Answer (score 2):

From all the reading I have done and from checking and comparing images I figure that this tea is *Assam Tea* or [Camellia sinesis var. assamica (Masters)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assam_tea) dried leafs.

Comment: Assam tea comes from the Assam region of India, not from Burma/Myanmar. Burmese tea doesn't seem to be readily available in North America, but from what I can see, it's just called "Burmese tea," though I agree that it does seem to be _var. assamica_.